# Android get POJO after button is clicked within listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an `ImageButton` inside of a listviews children like so:

```
 <ImageButton 
      android:id="@+id/pick_up_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="pickUpDropOff"/>
```

That calls the `pickUpOrDropOff` method like this:

```
public void pickUpDropOff(View view) {

        ImageButton buttonToChange = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pick_up_button);

        if (buttonToChange.getTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG).toString() == "false") {
             buttonToChange.setImageResource(R.drawable.triangle_full);
             buttonToChange.setTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG, "true");
             ListItem itemToChange = parent
         }

         else if (buttonToChange.getTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG).toString() == "true") {
             buttonToChange.setImageResource(R.drawable.triangle_empty);
             buttonToChange.setTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG, "false");
         }

// do some other stuff
}
```

This does indeed change the image resource, but when the views get recycled the change in image resource doesn't persist, as my POJO atttribute for `pickedUp` has not been changed. How do I get the POJO in this case in order to change the attribute?

Comment: You can create a variable to control the image resource (array) and override the getView() method of list adapter to process the row of the list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just change the attribute of the pojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out.

To get the pojo for the button clicked, set a tag in the adapter with the objects position like so:

```
pickUpButton.setTag(R.integer.LIST_ITEM_POSITION, position);
```

Then when the button is clicked, I change the underlying pojo like this (my Model is `ShoppingListItem`):

```
ImageButton buttonToChange = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pick_up_button);

if (buttonToChange.getTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG).toString() == "false") {
     buttonToChange.setImageResource(R.drawable.triangle_full);
     int myPosition = (Integer) buttonToChange.getTag(R.integer.LIST_ITEM_POSITION);
     ShoppingListItem itemToChange = shoppingListItems.get(myPosition);
     itemToChange.setPickedUp(true);
 }

 else if (buttonToChange.getTag(R.bool.PICKED_UP_TAG).toString() == "true") {
     buttonToChange.setImageResource(R.drawable.triangle_empty);
     int myPosition = (Integer) buttonToChange.getTag(R.integer.LIST_ITEM_POSITION);
     ShoppingListItem itemToChange = shoppingListItems.get(myPosition);
     itemToChange.setPickedUp(false);
 }

listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will stop the issue of non persisting data with recycling listviews. For me, there is no local storage of this data (all comes and goes via JSON api). Be sure to persist changes to the database if your app calls for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the notifydatasetchange() on listview adapter after you change your pojo data source like this

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Yes, I know how to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I haven't changed the data set. That's what my question is asking - how do I change the attributes for the corresponding pojo of the button that is clicked. Did you read the question?